# Is it possible to persist partial data selectively in Ignite?

Tags: persistence, ignite

Just wanted to find out if it's possible to persist subsets of the data, say only some tables, columns and/or rows, filtered by some conditions.  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to control if an entire cache/table needs to be persisted. Create a [data region](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-configuration#section-data-regions) with persistence enabled and start/store all the caches there.